# resize an iframe

Tags: iframe, resize

Want to take a div and find for iframe tag, and see if it have a width and height, if so change them to numbers i give, if not, add width and height to the iframe .

```
<div class="player container">

    <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/"</iframe>  

</div>
```

i just don't know how to do it, if you could help me, it's will be my pleasure.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Javascript:-

```
  <script type=&#34;text/javascript&#34;>
 <!--//
  function sizeFrame&#40;frameId&#41; {
  var F = document.getElementById&#40;frameId&#41;;
  if&#40;F.contentDocument&#41; {
   F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and Chrome
 } else {

 F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome

 }

}

 window.onload=sizeFrame; 

 //-->
</script>

<iframe width=&#34;100%&#34; id=&#34;myFrame&#34; src=&#34;testincludegallery.php?id=1&#34; scrolling=&#34;no&#34; frameborder=&#34;0&#34; onload=&#34;window.parent.sizeFrame&#40;&#39;myFrame&#39;&#41;;&#34;>
```

Comment: i have made this code but i doesn't work, var iframe = $("div.player").find("iframe");
  iframe.addClass('container');

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = $("div").find("iframe");
var w = iframe.width();
var h = iframe.height();

iframe.attr('width', (w)?w+num:num);
iframe.attr('height', (h)?h+num:num);
```